# How do I query, update, insert rows into an SQLite database (a .sqlite file) using Sinatra?

Tags: ruby, database, sqlite, sinatra

I'm used to writing PHP queries to databases (i.e., queries that looks like SQL syntax), but I'm confused on how to do this in Ruby's Sinatra gem.

None of the documentation or tutorials I found online indicate that Sinatra is similar to PHP.

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I understand the matter, Sinatra isn't created for database queries. It's a DSL which makes easier creating applications for getting requests from the web-server and forming responses. To work with databases there are two approaches: using the [ruby bindings](http://rdoc.info/gems/sqlite3/frames) to a database or using [ORMs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping). The last approach is wide spread and preferable in modern Ruby web-development. Here's the list of ORMs which you can use to work with databases making web-applications in Sinatra:

- [Sequel](http://sequel.rubyforge.org/documentation.html)
- [DataMapper](http://datamapper.org/)
- [ActiveRecord](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-FJZQSHn7fc) (which itself is the part of Ruby on Rails but you can use it outside the framework)

Comment: Ah, I think I see. Incidentally, I found this interesting video tutorial combining web-scraping with Sinatra: http://hunterpowers.com/data-scraping-and-more-with-ruby-nokogiri-sinatra-and-heroku/. After viewing the last section, I made my own testing .erb and .rb file where I basically call a variable that executes an sqlite3 gem's command. Are there major disadvantages to this as compared to the other methods? I can be more specific if you need me to clarify. Thanks for answering.

Comment: I seriously recommend using Active Record or Sequel for your DB interaction. DataMapper doesn't seem to be very popular or well supported. As a learning experiment I gave DataMapper a red-hot go and found that is was great for very simple stuff but came away lacking when the complexity rose.